# Play music automatically after start pomodoro gnome task

Tags: gnome, vlc, music

I have installed [**gnome pomodoro** plugin](https://gnomepomodoro.org/), so it have action capability by every task like this:

[image]

So I like to play music from one saved playlist with random selection shuffle during **pomodoro** time. And i have this kind of playlist with VLC like this:

[image]

How can I do this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example my play list file path is `/home/pratap/Downloads/VLC/myPlaylist.xspf`

replace your playlists file path in below command and test it.

```
vlc --random --playlist-autostart /home/pratap/Downloads/VLC/myPlayList.xspf
```

Once you are sure it is working.. Then add the command to pomodoro

[image]

Tested in Ubuntu 20.04

[image]

Comment: Also, to play an online stream `streamlink --player="nice -n 19 mpv --no-video" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qap5aO4i9A" "best,720p,480p" |& tee /dev/null`